# Blank Minecraft game output

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Sometimes, when I look at my Minecraft game output, it goes totally blank:
[image: Minecraft console output window]

There was output, but it later disappeared.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe there's no output to see?

Comment: There was output. After a few moments when I checked again the entire window was blank.

Comment: From what I can see its modded minecraft? It may bring the output through the mods client instead of minecraft. suggestion i dont really know

Comment: This happens in Vanilla too, I just happened to be using LabyMod while taking this screenshot.

Comment: I've personally had this happen to me every now and then too - it's not connected to mods.